# How to define ration of summary with hugging face transformers pipeline?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using the following code to summarize an article from using huggingface-transformer's pipeline. Using this code:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
summarizer = pipeline(task="summarization" )
summary = summarizer(text)
print(summary[0]['summary_text'])
```

How can I define a ratio between the summary and the original article? For example, 20% of the original article?

EDIT 1: I implemented the solution you suggested, but got the following error. This is the code I used:

```
summarizer(text, min_length = int(0.1 * len(text)), max_length = int(0.2 * len(text)))
print(summary[0]['summary_text'])
```

The error I got:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-bc11c5d8eb66> in <module>()
----> 1 summarizer(text, min_length = int(0.1 * len(text)), max_length = int(0.2 * len(text)))
      2 print(summary[0]['summary_text'])

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1482         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1483         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1484     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1485 
   1486 

RuntimeError: index out of range: Tried to access index 1026 out of table with 1025 rows. at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorEvenMoreMath.cpp:418
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note that this answer is based on the documentation for version 2.6 of transformers)

It seems that as of yet the documentation on the pipeline feature is still very shallow, which is why we have to dig a bit deeper. When calling a Python object, it internally references its own `__call__` property, which we can find [here for the summarization pipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/pipelines.html#SummarizationPipeline).

Note that it allows us (similar to the underlying [`BartForConditionalGeneration` model](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bart.html#transformers.BartForConditionalGeneration.generate)) to specifiy the `min_length` and `max_length`, which is why we can simply call with something like

```
summarizer(text, min_length = int(0.1 * len(text)), max_length = int(0.2 * len(text)))
```

This would give you a summary of about 10-20% length of the original data, but of course you can change that to your liking. Note that the default value for `BartForConditionalGeneration` for `max_length` is 20 (as of now, `min_length` is undocumented, but defaults to 0), whereas the summarization pipeline has values `min_length=21` and `max_length=142`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Please check the edits @dennlinger

Comment: Can you please specify the value of `text` then? And which version of `transformers` are you running on?

Comment: Here is the text - https://pastebin.com/XTy2gWQf and I am using ```transformers==2.6.0```

Comment: Pretrained Bart only supports input lengths of up to 1024 tokens. Therefore, the issue is clearly that your mentioned text is too long. (For future reference, since pastebin links expire, the text was spanning several paragraphs). Your best bet at this point would be to split into different sections and then summarize each of those.

Comment: Ahh. In BERT, what is 1 token defined as?

Comment: I meant BART. Thanks!

Comment: I think this merits another question, and has (in slight relation) been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960995/how-are-the-tokenembeddings-in-bert-created). Essentially, most approaches use subword-units, which can somewhat be compared to syllables (that's *only an illustrative comparison* and not the actual results). You can see those in a model's `vocab` file.

Comment: @dennlinger, I liked this ratio approach, but it was giving me ValueErrors like:

`ValueError: min_length has to be a non-negative integer, but is 226.60000000000002` 

Fixed this via:

`max_length = math.floor(0.25 * len(document))`

Comment: Great catch! I've rectified the above formula by casting it to `int` manually. This should fix any such error messages. `math.floor` is the slightly more verbose, but definitely more elegant way of ensuring correct roundings.